# Graph API - Profile (not page) - Album Image - Comments

Tags: facebook, graph, permissions, comments

I have a little problem with maybe the facebook permissions.

My client want's to import comments on his pictures in his public album (not from facebook page) to his website.

I did the whole thing except that facebook returns only my(the person who got access token using login with facebook) comments? In other words, it returns only comments that are made by the owner of the access token.

What I need is to get all the comments.

In Graph Explorer if  I select:
"Application" => "Graph API Explorer" and i generate access token  it returns all comments

In Graph Explorer if  I select:
"Application" => "ExampleMyAppName" then it cannot fetch comments of  other users, only comments of the owner of the access token.

I use "user_photos" in facebook login and in my application it's under  review.

Is there any way to fetch all comments from all users on given photo?

Thank you

Comment: not sure why it works with the api explorer app (maybe because you can use an older api version with it?), but you should not get that information anyway for privacy reasons...

Comment: Thanks, so basically there is no way export public comments on public image in public album on a public profile (not page) to website right?

Comment: i guess (and hope) not, after the recent scandal it would be weird if it would be possible imho.